# How to make a checkbox checked by default and also retrieve old value from database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox, laravel-4

I have a checkbox and i want to make my checkbox checked by default, if the user unchecks the checkbox and save the form, i need the checkbox to be unchecked while retrieving or editing the form data.

**My view page**

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('active') ? 'error' : '' }}">
                <label for="active" class="col-md-3 control-label">@lang('admin/assetdetails/form.active')</label>
                     <div class="controls col-md-7">
                            {{ Form::checkbox('active', 1, Input::old('active', $assetdetail->active), array('class'=>'isnesdbox')) }}
                            {{ $errors->first('active', '<span class="alert-msg"><i class="icon-remove-sign"></i> :message</span>') }}
                     </div>
            </div>
```

**Giving this brings back the old data from database correctly but i couldn't make my checkbox checked as default**

**Controller:**

```
public function postEdit($assetdetailId = null)
    {
        // Check if the location exists
        if (is_null($assetdetail = Assetdetail::find($assetdetailId)))
        {
            // Redirect to the blogs management page
            return Redirect::to('admin/settings/assetdetails')->with('error', Lang::get('admin/assetdetails/message.does_not_exist'));
        }



        // get the POST data
        $new = Input::all();

        // attempt validation
        if ($assetdetail->validate($new))
        {

            // Update the location data

            $assetdetail ->asset_number             = e(Input::get('asset_number'));
            $assetdetail ->location_id              = e(Input::get('location_id'));
            $assetdetail ->assign_to                = e(Input::get('assign_to'));
            $assetdetail ->asset_type_id            = e(Input::get('asset_type_id'));
            $assetdetail ->nesd                     = e(Input::get('nesd'));
            $assetdetail ->active                   = e(Input::get('active'));
            $assetdetail ->shift                    = e(Input::get('shift'));
            $assetdetail ->supplier_name            = e(Input::get('supplier_name'));
            $assetdetail ->description              = e(Input::get('description'));
            $assetdetail ->dateof_purchase          = e(Input::get('dateof_purchase'));
            $assetdetail ->label_number             = e(Input::get('label_number'));
            $assetdetail ->purchase_price           = e(Input::get('purchase_price'));
            $assetdetail ->dateof_disposed          = e(Input::get('dateof_disposed'));
            $assetdetail ->depreciation_type        = e(Input::get('depreciation_type'));
            $assetdetail ->salvage_value            = e(Input::get('salvage_value'));
            $assetdetail ->asset_life               = e(Input::get('asset_life'));




            // Was the asset created?
            if($assetdetail->save())
            {
                // Redirect to the saved location page
                return Redirect::to("admin/settings/assetdetails/$assetdetailId/edit")->with('success', Lang::get('admin/assetdetails/message.update.success'));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // failure
            $errors = $assetdetail->errors();
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($errors);
        }

        // Redirect to the location management page
        return Redirect::to("admin/settings/assetdetails/$assetdetailId/edit")->with('error', Lang::get('admin/assetdetails/message.update.error'));

    }
```

**I tried**

```
{{ Form::checkbox('active', 1, true, Input::old('active', $assetdetail->active), array('class'=>'isnesdbox')) }}
```

But i get the follwing error

Cannot use a scalar value as an array

**I also tried this**

```
<input class="col-md-1 controls isnesdbox" type="checkbox" name="active" checked id="active" value="1" {{ $assetdetail->active === '1' ? 'checked' : '' }} />
```

Please help me to achieve this
Note:iam using mysql database and the database type iam using is bit which stores 0's and 1's depending on the user input.

Comment: You do realize your last example has `checked` attribute before the blade tags, right? Try removing it.

Comment: @Raphael_ Yes i know that i have checked attribute in my last example,i gave it purposely just because i need my checkbox checked defaultly as well as retrieving the old data as i mentioned above.Both the first and last example are retrieving the data correctly but what about making it checked by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you don't really care what the value of $assetdetail->active is, you just want the checkbox checked until the user unchecks it.

Does this do what you're looking for:

```
{{ Form::checkbox('active', 1, Session::hasOldInput() ? array_key_exists('active', Input::old()) : true, array('class'=>'isnesdbox')) }}
```

Or have I misread what you're trying to do?

For this solution, it checks if there is old input in the session.  If there is old input data, it uses the existence of the `'active'` key to determine the state of the checkbox [1].  If there is not old input data, it defaults the checkbox to checked.

[1] Checkboxes submit differently then other form elements.  An unchecked checkbox is not considered a "successful" control, so it does not submit any data, and will therefore not exist in the `Input::old()` array.  So, if the key exists, it was checked; if the key does not exist, it was not checked.  You can read more about "successful" form controls [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2).

---

### Edit

Based on the comments, it looks like the same form is used for both creating and editing the Assetdetail object.  When creating, you want the checkbox checked by default, when editing you want the checkbox to reflect the value stored in the database.

The code I posted above should be close, but you'll need to change the hardcoded `true` in the ternary operator.

If $assetdetail is null during create, you'll want:

```
{{ Form::checkbox('active', 1, Session::hasOldInput() ? array_key_exists('active', Input::old()) : (!empty($assetdetail) ? $assetdetail->active : true), array('class'=>'isnesdbox')) }}
```

If $assetdetail is an Assetdetail instance during create, you'll want:

```
{{ Form::checkbox('active', 1, Session::hasOldInput() ? array_key_exists('active', Input::old()) : ($assetdetail->exists ? $assetdetail->active : true), array('class'=>'isnesdbox')) }}
```

Comment: u misunderstood what i said, before submitting the form data the checkbox field will be checked defaultly,if the user unchecks the defaultly checked checkbox and submits the form value 0 will be saved in database i want to fetch this value while editing the form.so if user unchecks the checkbox and save the form data the active field should not be checked while editing the form. While editing your answer checks the checkbox even if the user unchecks the checkbox and saves the form, as u have coded in such a way that if there is not old input data, it defaults the checkbox to checked.

Comment: @megamage So, is this a form for both creating and editing Assetdetail objects?  When creating one, you want the checkbox checked by default, but when editing one, you want the checkbox to reflect the value stored in the database?

Comment: yes u are right the form is same for creating and editing Assetdetail objects and i need checkbox checked by default while creating and reflect the value stored in the database while editing.

Comment: @megamage I updated my answer to suggest another solution based on the new information.

Comment: yes $assetdetail is an Assetdetail instance during create and your code worked like charm.Thank u very much for your time,i appreciate this help.Can u please explain this code.

Answer (score 11):

Since Google apparently still thinks this answer is relevant, here's an updated answer for Laravel 5.8:

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="notify" @if(!old() || old('notify') == 'true') checked="checked" @endif />
```

Answer (score 0):

### For variable-based default value

In below, if `$myDefault` is set to `true`, it equals checking the check-box by default.

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="myOnValue"
       name="myField"
       @if((!old() && $myDefault) || old('myField') == 'myOnValue') checked="checked" @endif />
```

### Always checked by default

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="on"
       name="myField"
       @if(!old() || old('myField') == 'on') checked="checked" @endif />
```

### Always unchecked by default

Below does not need "`!old()`" workaround.

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="on"
       name="myField"
       @if(old('myField') == 'on') checked="checked" @endif />
```

> Related Laracast: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-set-old-value-for-checkbox-input-using-blade?page=1&replyId=771230