# Old Data for Check Box

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

How Can I get old value for the below check boxes

```
  @if (count($chests) > 0)
          @foreach ($chests as $chest)
          <br>  Day:
                @for ($i = 0; $i < $days; $i++)
                  <label><input type="checkbox" name="{{str_replace(' ', '_', $chest->name)}}_days[]"
                    value="{{$i+1}}">{{$i+1}}</label>

                @endfor
                <br>
              <label><input type="checkbox" name="chest[]" value="{{$chest->name}}">{{$chest->name}}</label><br>
              <div id="div01">
              <input type="text" id ="hint" name="{{str_replace(' ', '_', $chest->name)}}_hints[]" placeholder="Hints / Repeats etc">
              </div>
          @endforeach
          @else
            No Register Machines
          @endif
```

How I get the old value of checkbox

Comment: Not sure what you are ask? Please add some explaination as well as expected output.

Comment: I need the old data of the check box, eg         <option value="1"{{ old('searchUsers') == 1 ? 'selected' : '' }}>Name</option>

Comment: what is old data you just added a for loop here no idea what is question.

Comment: when this for loop work? what is layout after submit?

Comment: I edited my 1st post with full code

Comment: <input type="text" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}">

Comment: ok but for this               <label><input type="checkbox" name="chest[]" value="{{$chest->name}}">{{$chest->name}}</label><br>

Comment: This might be help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39521726/how-to-show-old-data-of-checkbox-in-laravel

Comment: the example that you send me has a static name, my is changing name<label><input type="checkbox" name="{{str_replace(' ', '_', $chest->name)}}_days[]"
                        value="{{$i+1}}">{{$i+1}}</label>