# how can make a radio button remember the previous option that given by a user at edit.blade.php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, radio-button

```
                              /*edit.blade.php*/
                                    <div class="form-group ">
                                      <p>{{Form::label('Status', 'Κατάσταση :')}} 

                                    Άριστη {{Form::radio('status', 'Άριστη')}}
                                    Καλή {{Form::radio('status', 'Καλή')}}
                                    Μέτρια {{Form::radio('status', 'Μέτρια')}}
                                    Κακή {{Form::radio('status', 'Κακή')}}</p>
                                   </div>
```

/*when the user click to  edit posts i want the radio button remember the previous option that given by a  user */

Comment: Pass the current values as an array to your blade view and set them by setting the `value` in the radio button. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39524462/3585500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a new resource you can achieve what you want with this construct:

```
{{ Form::radio('status', 'Άριστη', old('status') == 'Άριστη') }}
```

You can also add a second parameter to `old()` and reuse it when editing an existing resource entry:

```
{{ Form::radio('status', 'Άριστη', old('status', $resource->status ?? '') == 'Άριστη') }}
```