# using old on checkbox

Tags: laravel, foreach, view

I have a checklist which was generate in a `@foreach`. I have one simple question. How can I use `{{ old() }}` in this example. My foreach:

```
@foreach($c->tags as $tag)
    <li><label><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="{{ $tag->id }}"> {{ $tag->name }}</label></li>
@endforeach
```

I want to know if my checkbox was check (after submitting, if I'll have errors). In input text is simple `{{ old('name') }}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a checkbox checked by default and also retrieve old value from database in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530261/how-to-make-a-checkbox-checked-by-default-and-also-retrieve-old-value-from-datab)

Answer (score 2):

Make a check to see if it exists and check it if it does. In its basic form:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="example" @if(old('example')) checked @endif>
```

Comment: It won't solve my problem becouse you have only one checkbox but I have an array.

Answer (score 0):

For one:

```php
<input type="checkbox" name="example" {{ !old('example') ?: 'checked' }}>
```

For many:

```php
<input type="checkbox" name="example[]" value="val" @if (is_array(old('example')) && in_array('val', old('example'))) checked @endif>
```