# Laravel - old() value of checkbox, in combination with the one loaded from the database

Tags: laravel, checkbox

I have this checkbox code:

```
<div>
     <input type="checkbox" id="allowfullscreen" name="allowfullscreen"
                                 {{ $gallery->allowfullscreen == 1 ? 'checked' : '' }}>
</div>
```

This checks the checkbox based on the value taken from the database. Now, i would like to implement also the old data, in case of a failed submission.

For textboxes i do it like this:

```
<input id="galname"
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control @error('galname') is-invalid @enderror"
                        name="galname"
                        value="{{ old('galname') ?? $gallery->galname }}"
                        required autocomplete="galname" autofocus>
```

But it does not work this way for checkboxes since they need `checked` to be printed. The samples I found around here on SO only adress one of the two situations, but didnt find any that address both things for checkboxes.

How can this be done?

Comment: why u don't handle it from controller on failed submission? also i'm pretty sure when u're trying use `??` for your value, u also need a `:`, because it's doing `if() with?? and else :`, and this might be the problem. maybe more code to share to see what is exact problem.

Comment: Hello! thanks for your answer.. actually both codes above are working.. but what I would need is to expand the condition in the checkboxcode in order to be able to include the old() value in case of failed submission..

Comment: you mean by expand, is like writing your condition like using if-else, i think u need to expand it like this: `$gallery->allowfullscreen == 1 || $gallery->allowfullscreen == 5 ? 'checked' : 'etc' : ''`
i think this was the way how u shouold use it.
`'checked' doing if()` , `'etc' doing if else`, `' ' doing else`.

Comment: the condition should be: `if (old('allowfullscreen')!=null) { if (old('allowfullscreen') == 1){echo "checked";} } else { if($gallery->allowfullscreen == 1){echo "checked";} } ` but how to write it decently?

Comment: try this :
` (old('allowfullscreen')!=null ? (old('allowfullscreen') == 1 ?  'checked' : '') : ($gallery->allowfullscreen == 1 ? 'checked' : '')); `

Comment: ok, it is not working, because if the ckeckbox is not checked, then the value returns null.. so if the checkbox is not chekced it returns the database value.. I am startin gto think that this is not doable.. it should load from database only the first time thepage loads.. then it should keep the old() values until submission..

Comment: i shouldn't wright your code, but i'm giving you clue to do it, first i gave u an example, then i wrote an example base on your code, you're returning null because base on your statement you didn't handle any condition to return unchecked. i'm gonna give u then answer this time, but try to learn it. `(old('allowfullscreen')!=null ? (old('allowfullscreen') == 1 ?  1 : 0) : ($gallery->allowfullscreen == 1 ? 1 : 0));` this is for your conditions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a checkbox checked by default and also retrieve old value from database in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530261/how-to-make-a-checkbox-checked-by-default-and-also-retrieve-old-value-from-datab)

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter you give the the `old()` function is used when the first value is null. So when you do `old('name', "test")` and no old value for 'name' is found, 'test' is used. So in your case, you could use:

```
<div>
     <input type="checkbox" id="allowfullscreen" name="allowfullscreen"
                                 {{ old('allowfullscreen', $gallery->allowfullscreen) == 1 ? 'checked' : '' }}>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but it does not work.. example: database is true. -> load page, checkbox is set. -> remove check, and submit -> fails because of other field validation -> old is null because null is sent also if the checkbox is not selected, -> picks value from database again...

Answer (score 0):

This is ok even if you use all inputs in one blade template to use with create and update actions.
Will only work for `POST` request, obviously.

`@if(old('published', (old('_token') ? false : ($slider->published ?? false)))) checked @endif`

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="publish" name="published" value="1" @if(old('published', (old('_token') ? false : ($slider->published ?? false)))) checked @endif>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="publish">{{ __('Publié') }}</label>
    @include('bo.modules.input-error', ['inputName'=>'published'])
</div>
```

Using this on request

```
/**
 * Prepare the data for validation.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    $this->merge([
        'published' => $this->published ? true : false
    ]);
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'published' => 'required|boolean',
    ];
}
```