# Edit form issue with default value for checkbox regarding old value on error

Tags: php, laravel, forms, checkbox

I have a problem that seems like a bug with the Laravel checkbox `old()` value. I have a code where I want to fill default values on edit and, if the form submit fails, I want to fill `old()` value to the form.

The problem is when the original database value is TRUE and the new form submit is false for the checkbox. Laravel `old()` does not catch the FALSE value on submit for checkbox and fills the original value which is TRUE.

```
<input name="active" type="checkbox"
    @if( old('active', $voucher->active ?? false) ) checked='checked' @endif
>
```

It falls back to the default value if submit is FALSE. All solutions I found are wrong. How can I solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a checkbox checked by default and also retrieve old value from database in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530261/how-to-make-a-checkbox-checked-by-default-and-also-retrieve-old-value-from-datab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution would be to test another field like @old('submit')

```
<input name="active" type="checkbox"
    @if( old('active') || (!old('submit') && $voucher->active) ) checked='checked' @endif
>
```

which is send by submit. It seems it works but dont know if it is always send or if there is a use case where submit could be empty.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be

```
<input name="active" type="checkbox"  value="{{old('active', $voucher->active ?? 0)}}" {{isset($voucher->active)?'checked':''}}>
```

still want to check if its true or not or 1 or 0 you can check like below

```
<input name="active" type="checkbox" value="{{old('active', $voucher->active ?? 0)}}" {{(isset($voucher->active)&&$voucher->active==true)?'checked':''}}>
```

As per me.for your requirement checkbox is not suitable one .Better you have to go for radio button .So user can choose true or false on active

Comment: This is TRUE if submit send FALSE and original value is TRUE. It has to be FALSE in this case.

Comment: then you have to set value="{{old('active', $voucher->active ?? false)}}"

Comment: Dont understand it. It looks like a hack and I am not sure about it.

Comment: can you try value="{{old('active', isset($active)&&$active==true?1: 0)}}" but its not user-friendly as per me .since checkbox will definitely clicked not clicked at all

Comment: i suggest you use radio button so you can provide yes or no or true or false

Comment: Radio buttons are not checkboxes.

Comment: yes i know .its opinion to convert checkbox to radio button.but you might have used for as per your requirements

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="active" value="1"
    @if((old('_token') && old('active') != null) || (old('_token') == null && $voucher->active))
    checked 
    @endif
>
```

Comment: it looks like more complicated then my solution. Did you read it?

Comment: What if I don't use 'submit' name in form from your solution?

Comment: The solution with _token is nice. But in most cases you wrote this code. So you know what is the name of your submit button.